# How to add kiosk mode in existing react native app?

Tags: android, react-native, kiosk-mode

Hi my react native app in production for last 2 years now i want to add new feature like kiosk mode one of module in my app in android only  is there any possible to enable kiosk mode in particular module i don't want to loose users and users dont delete any account in devices please help if any possibile for kiosk mode enable for already existing users